# Defining and executing large matrix operators on vectors efficiently

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review, code, quantum-computing

For an $N$-qubit system, I am interested in coding, in an efficient way, the following set of Kraus operators $\{A_c\}_c$ defined in the computational basis as
\begin{align}
     \hat{A}_c := \sum_{m=0}^{N}\sqrt{ \text{Pr}(N-m|c)}\sum_{\underline{M}}\underbrace{\big| \uparrow \cdot\cdot\cdot\downarrow_{j_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot \downarrow_{j_m} \cdot\cdot\cdot\uparrow \big\rangle}_\text{$N$-qubits} \big\langle \uparrow \cdot\cdot\cdot\downarrow_{j_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot \downarrow_{j_m}\cdot\cdot\cdot\uparrow \big|,\label{Ac}
    \end{align}

where $\underline{M}$ denotes the set of all binary permutations with $m$-spin down qubits and
\begin{align}
\text{Pr}\big(x|c\big):= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}}\exp \bigg[-\frac{(x-c)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \bigg].\label{Pr}    
\end{align}
As is stands the code does work but it is inefficient and has trouble computing beyond $N=10$. The main inefficient part is the final 4 lines.

```
(* System size N *)
Num = 8;
(* Spin-up and spin-down vectors *)
SU := {{1}, {0}} ; SD := {{0}, {1}};
(* Defining the Measurement Operators *)
B = GatherBy[Tuples[{0, 1}, Num], Total]; Ref = Flatten[B, 1];
B2 = {}; T = B /. {{0 -> SU, 1 -> SD}  }; T = Flatten[T, 2];
Do[ AppendTo[B2, KroneckerProduct @@ T[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[T]}];
Pr[x_, c_] := (1/Sqrt[
     2 \[Pi] (\[Sigma]^2) ] ) Exp[-((x - c)^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))];
AC = {}; 
Do[AppendTo[AC, 
   M = KroneckerProduct[\[Sqrt] Pr[Count[Ref[[i]], 0], c]*B2[[i]] , 
     ConjugateTranspose[B2[[i]]]]], {i, 1, Length[B2]}];
(* Final result *)
AC2 = Sum[AC[[i]], {i, 1, Length[AC]}];
```

I have about 250GB of RAM available yet I still seem to run out of memory. Does anyone have an idea of how to improve the code. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Your `AC` contains $2^N$ dense matrices of size $2^N \times 2^N$, so if each entry uses 8 byte (which is optimistic since you have symbolic entries) that will be $8 \cdot 2^{3N}$ bytes, which for $N=11$ would be 69 GByte. The solution is to construct `AC2` without constructing `AC` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Num=3;
Pr[x_,c_]:=(1/Sqrt[2*Pi(σ^2)]) Exp[-((x-c)^2/(2*σ^2))];

AC2=DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[
      Map[Sqrt[Pr[Count[#,0],c]]&,Tuples[{0,1},Num]]]];
```

This produces a sparse array. To get a normal array, use `Normal[AC2]`.

Comment: Is the SparseArray function necessary, it seems that removing it still yields the same result? Thanks.

Comment: Yes and no. Yes in the sense that `Normal[DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[...]]]` yields the same thing as just `DiagonalMatrix[...]`. No in the sense that, if all you are doing with this matrix is to apply it to vectors, then you should stick with the `AC2` in my answer (with `DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[...]]`) and never apply `Normal` to it. By applying `Normal`, all you are doing is creating a huge matrix with lots of zeros, that is not a good way to use your memory.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In your comment you seem to be referring to removing the Normal function...What I was referring to was removing the SparseArray function and just using the DiagonalMatrix function, this seems to yield the same result.

Comment: My sentence "Yes in the sense that..." is about removing both SparseArray and Normal. You should definitely learn about sparse matrices if you are working with large matrices, see [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebra.html#17571) for example.

Answer (score 2):

"AppendTo" is notoriously slow. The same for loops. Use "Table" instead. Your code takes 5.7 sec on my machine and the code below: 1.6 sec.

```
(*System size N*)Num = 8;
(*Spin-up and spin-down vectors*)
SU = {{1}, {0}}; SD = {{0}, {1}};
(*Defining the Measurement Operators*)
B = GatherBy[Tuples[{0, 1}, Num], Total]; Ref = Flatten[B, 1];
T = B /. {{0 -> SU, 1 -> SD}}; T = Flatten[T, 2];
B2 = Table[KroneckerProduct @@ T[[i]], {i, 1, Length[T]}];
Pr[x_, c_] := (1/
     Sqrt[2 \[Pi] (\[Sigma]^2)]) Exp[-((x - c)^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))];
AC = Table[
   KroneckerProduct[\[Sqrt]Pr[Count[Ref[[i]], 0], c]*B2[[i]], 
    ConjugateTranspose[B2[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[B2]}];
(*Final result*)
AC2 = Total[AC];
```